# Change the object name for com DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

We have a com component from third party and using that com dll from the vb script. We want to remove the third party dll dependency and write our own COM component with same name and object so that we dont need to change anything in our scripting code.

I created the new project with same dll name and class name.But some how in the rgs file it is showing the name differently

original thirdparty object name is ReadWriteFileDataLibrary.ReadWriteFileDataAPILib

The project which I created have the below name in rgs file
VersionIndependentProgID = s 'ReadWriteFileDataLibrary.ReadWriteFileDataAPI'

The last three letters(Lib) are missing . Is it possible change the name same as the old dll?

I am new to COM so I dont have much idea about it

Answer (score 0):

The object name comes from the [`coclass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/anatomy-of-an-idl-file) statement in the IDL file. You can change the name there (from *ReadWriteFileDataAPI* to *ReadWriteFileDataAPILib*), then check for other places in the code that may need to be fixed to use the new name. Whether and where such places might exist depends on how the C++ COM code was generated and laid out, which the question did not specify.

The RGS file will be regenerated with the new object name next time the project is built.

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse. I have checked the IDL file and it has the correct name only but in the RGS file the object name is getting truncated as mentioned in the question. RGS file is not updating evertyime I build the project. I have directly changed the object name in RGS file and it is working fine. I dont know whether it is correct way or not

Comment: @krishna That is hard to answer or even guess without seeing the full project, unfortunately.